# I'm having a problem getting the cdkDragDrop to place the checker in the new spot

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cdk-drag-drop

If I take off the cdkDropList, the checker moves and stays where I move it. If I add the cdkDropList it will move and then go back to its original position. I need to keep the cdkDropList in order to be able to get the event.containter.data and the event.previousContainer.data. Any thoughts on how to fix it would be appreciated.

Here's the html code

```
<div class="checkerboard-wrapper" cdkDropListGroup>
    <div *ngFor="let item of items;let i=index">
        <div id={{item.squareId}} class={{item.class}} cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="item" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">

            <div *ngIf="newGame" class="images">
                <img loading="lazy" *ngIf="item.img" id={{i}} class="checkerImg" src={{item.img}} cdkDrag />
                <div *cdkDragPlaceholder></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChildren, QueryList, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkDragDrop, CdkDragEnd, moveItemInArray, transferArrayItem } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { BreakpointState } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { HideDirective } from '../../directives/hide.directive';

import { SharedService } from '../../services/shared.service';
import { ScreenService } from '../../services/screen.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-checkerboard',
  templateUrl: './checkerboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./checkerboard.component.css'],

})
export class CheckerboardComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  isBelowLg: boolean = false;
  disabled: boolean = false;
  newGame: boolean = false;
  currentIndex;
  previousIndex;
  imgId: string;
  @ViewChildren(HideDirective) hideDirectives!: QueryList<HideDirective>;
  xPointerGrabPosition: number;
  yPointerGrabPosition: number;
  xPointerReleasePosition: number;
  yPointerReleasePosition: number;
  items: Array<any> = [
    { squareId: '1-1', id: '1', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '1-2', id: '2', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: ' ../../assets/images/beige-checker-piece.svg' },
    { squareId: '1-3', id: '3', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '1-4', id: '4', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: ' ../../assets/images/beige-checker-piece.svg' },
    { squareId: '1-5', id: '5', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '1-6', id: '6', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: ' ../../assets/images/beige-checker-piece.svg' },
    { squareId: '1-7', id: '7', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '1-8', id: '8', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: ' ../../assets/images/beige-checker-piece.svg' },

    { squareId: '2-1', id: '9', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: ' ../../assets/images/beige-checker-piece.svg' },
    { squareId: '2-2', id: '10', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '2-3', id: '11', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: ' ../../assets/images/beige-checker-piece.svg' },
    { squareId: '2-4', id: '12', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '2-5', id: '13', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: ' ../../assets/images/beige-checker-piece.svg' },
    { squareId: '2-6', id: '14', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '2-7', id: '15', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: '../../assets/images/beige-checker-piece.svg' },
    { squareId: '2-8', id: '16', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },

    { squareId: '3-1', id: '17', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '3-2', id: '18', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: '../../assets/images/beige-checker-piece.svg' },
    { squareId: '3-3', id: '19', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '3-4', id: '20', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: '../../assets/images/beige-checker-piece.svg' },
    { squareId: '3-5', id: '21', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '3-6', id: '22', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: '../../assets/images/beige-checker-piece.svg' },
    { squareId: '3-7', id: '23', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '3-8', id: '24', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: '../../assets/images/beige-checker-piece.svg' },

    { squareId: '4-1', id: '25', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: '' },
    { squareId: '4-2', id: '26', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '4-3', id: '27', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: '' },
    { squareId: '4-4', id: '28', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '4-5', id: '29', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: '' },
    { squareId: '4-6', id: '30', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '4-7', id: '31', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: '' },
    { squareId: '4-8', id: '32', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },

    { squareId: '5-1', id: '33', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '5-2', id: '34', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: '' },
    { squareId: '5-3', id: '35', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '5-4', id: '36', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: '' },
    { squareId: '5-5', id: '37', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '5-6', id: '38', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: '' },
    { squareId: '5-7', id: '39', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '5-8', id: '40', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: '' },

    { squareId: '6-1', id: '41', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: '../../assets/images/gray-checker-piece.svg' },
    { squareId: '6-2', id: '42', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '6-3', id: '43', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: '../../assets/images/gray-checker-piece.svg' },
    { squareId: '6-4', id: '44', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '6-5', id: '45', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: '../../assets/images/gray-checker-piece.svg' },
    { squareId: '6-6', id: '46', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '6-7', id: '47', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: '../../assets/images/gray-checker-piece.svg' },
    { squareId: '6-8', id: '48', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },

    { squareId: '7-1', id: '49', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '7-2', id: '50', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: '../../assets/images/gray-checker-piece.svg' },
    { squareId: '7-3', id: '51', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '7-4', id: '52', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: '../../assets/images/gray-checker-piece.svg' },
    { squareId: '7-5', id: '53', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '7-6', id: '54', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: '../../assets/images/gray-checker-piece.svg' },
    { squareId: '7-7', id: '55', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '7-8', id: '56', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: '../../assets/images/gray-checker-piece.svg' },

    { squareId: '8-1', id: '57', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: '../../assets/images/gray-checker-piece.svg' },
    { squareId: '8-2', id: '58', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '8-3', id: '59', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: '../../assets/images/gray-checker-piece.svg' },
    { squareId: '8-4', id: '60', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '8-5', id: '61', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: '../../assets/images/gray-checker-piece.svg' },
    { squareId: '8-6', id: '62', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
    { squareId: '8-7', id: '63', class: 'square checkerboard-square-black', img: '../../assets/images/gray-checker-piece.svg' },
    { squareId: '8-8', id: '64', class: 'square checkerboard-square-red', img: '' },
  ];

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService, private screenService: ScreenService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sharedService.sendStartGame().subscribe(data => this.addPieces());
    this.sharedService.sendEndGame().subscribe(data => this.newGame = data);
  }

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<any>, id) {
    console.log('Do you see this');
    const fromData = event.previousContainer.data;
    const toData = event.container.data;
    console.log('This is the fromData', fromData);
    console.log('This is the toData', toData);
  }

  addPieces() {
    this.newGame = true;
    this.disabled = true;
    this.sharedService.player1Active.next(true);
  }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, Mwave, I feel that I explain very bad about your question in the another question you do it. I wrote an answer not about this concrete question else about how use two -or various- cdk-drop-list to change data

Answer (score 0):

Please make use of `moveItemInArray` and `transferArrayItem` methods from the cdk api.

```
if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
          moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
        } else {
          transferArrayItem(
            event.previousContainer.data,
            event.container.data,
            event.previousIndex,
            event.currentIndex,
          );
         
          }
```

Comment: really nop. You can see a cdkDropList as a component that allow drag/drop elements inside. the drop function allow us ask about the "data" of the cdkDropList. But the data can be an array (then you can use moveItemInArray and transferArrayItem -they are only [javascript functions](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/cdk/drag-drop/drag-utils.ts) to mannage two arrays) or not. In this case the "data" is a simple object

Answer (score 0):

About cdkDropList and how use to pass values.

A cdkDropList is only a component with property Data that allow drag/drop. but the data can be "anything". Really the name is not very "util".

Imagine two simples cdk-drop-list in the way. I "hardcode" the data property to One and Two

```
<div cdkDropListGroup class="board">
  <div class="dropList"
    cdkDropList
    cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal"
    [cdkDropListData]="'One'"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
  >
    <div cdkDrag >
      <div>One</div>
      <div *cdkDragPlaceholder class="none"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropList"
    cdkDropList
    cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal"
    [cdkDropListData]="'Two'"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
  >
    <div cdkDrag >
      <div>Two</div>
      <div *cdkDragPlaceholder class="none"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<code>
{{result}}
</code>
```

We can use

```
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<any>) {
    const fromData = event.previousContainer.data;
    const toData = event.container.data;
    this.result=fromData+"-->"+toData
  }
```

See that the only thing Angular is change the variable result when you drop one element from one cdk-drop-list to another. After executed the function drop, Angular "repaint" again the two cdk-drop-list. As we are not changed anything more the variable result looks like we are not dropped, but it's not true. Simply we are not change any more than the variable.

Well, more fun, in each cdkDropList we are going to have two "cdkDrag" elements

```
<div cdkDropListGroup class="board">
<div class="dropList vertical"
  cdkDropList
  [cdkDropListData]="'One'"
  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
>
  <div class="item" *ngFor="let i of [0,1]" cdkDrag >
    <div>One</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropList vertical"
  cdkDropList
  [cdkDropListData]="'Two'"
  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop2($event)"
>
  <div class="item" *ngFor="let i of [0,1]" cdkDrag >
    <div>Two</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<code>
{{result2}}
</code>
```

Now, you can get the "index" of the elements dropped and the position where dropped. Again, the only thing we are going to do is change the value of the variable result2 (so we see that the element is not "dropped")

```
  drop2(event: CdkDragDrop<any>) {
    const fromData = event.previousContainer.data;
    const toData = event.container.data;
    this.result2=fromData+"("+event.previousIndex+")-->"+toData+"("+event.currentIndex+")"
  }
```

Well, we can imagine what happens when we use an array instead "hardcode" the cdk-drag elements and how we can imagine a functions to interchange elements between the array.

Now we are make some more interesting, we are going to define an array

```
  myArray=[{id:1,name:'One'},{id:2,name:'Two'}]
```

And the "data" for the first cdk-drag-lisk is the element myArray[0] and the "data" for the second cdk-drag-list is the element myArray[1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f75msf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

```
<div cdkDropListGroup class="board">
<div class="dropList"
  cdkDropList
  cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal"
  [cdkDropListData]="myArray[0]"
  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop3($event)"
>
  <div cdkDrag >
    <div>{{myArray[0].name}}</div>
    <div *cdkDragPlaceholder class="none"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropList"
  cdkDropList
  cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal"
  [cdkDropListData]="myArray[1]"
  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop3($event)"
>
  <div cdkDrag >
    <div>{{myArray[1].name}}</div>
    <div *cdkDragPlaceholder class="none"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<code>
{{myArray|json}}
</code>
```

Now in the function drop we are going to interchange the property "name" of the two arrays

```
  drop3(event: CdkDragDrop<any>) {
    const fromData = event.previousContainer.data;
    const toData = event.container.data;
    const value=fromData.name
    fromData.name=toData.name
    toData.name=value
  }
```

See that the only change is the property "name" (the property "id" is unaltered)

See that we are choose that the data was myArray[0] and myArray[1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f75msf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) but also can simply the data was 0 and 1

```
<div cdkDropListGroup class="board">
<div class="dropList"
  cdkDropList
  cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal"
  [cdkDropListData]="0"
  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop4($event)"
>
  <div cdkDrag >
    <div>{{myArray[0].name}}</div>
    <div *cdkDragPlaceholder class="none"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropList"
  cdkDropList
  cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal"
  [cdkDropListData]="1"
  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop4($event)"
>
  <div cdkDrag >
    <div>{{myArray[1].name}}</div>
    <div *cdkDragPlaceholder class="none"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<code>
{{myArray|json}}
</code>
```

And our function

```
  drop4(event: CdkDragDrop<any>) {
    const fromData = event.previousContainer.data;
    const toData = event.container.data;
    const value=this.myArray[fromData].name
    this.myArray[fromData].name=this.myArray[toData].name
    this.myArray[toData].name=value
  }
```

You can see the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f75msf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)